# Get substrings from text which start with one of an array of keywords and the substring must not include a second keyword

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I want write some function that were accept two parameters `$text` and `$keys`. Keys that an array with keys.

At the output we need to get an array, where the keys will be the keys passed to the function (if we found them in the text), and the values ​​will be the text that follows this key, until it comes across the next key or the text ends. If the key is repeated in the text, write only the last value to the array

**For example:**

*Visualized Text:* Lorem Ipsum is simply **one** dummy text of the printing and  **two** typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's **one** standard dummy text ever since the **three** 1500s.

```
$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply one dummy text of the printing and  two typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s one standard dummy text ever since the three 1500s.';

$keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Desired Output:

```
[
    'one' => 'standard dummy text ever since the',
    'two' => 'typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s',
    'three' => '1500s.'
]
```

I tried writing a regular expression which will cope with this task, but without success.

Last attempt:

```
function getKeyedSections($text, $keys) {
    $keysArray = explode(',', $keys);
    $pattern = '/(?:' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keysArray)) . '):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keysArray)) . '):\s*|\z)/s';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);

    $keyedSections = [];
    foreach ($keysArray as $key) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $value) {
            if (stripos($matches[0][$index], $key) !== false) {
                $keyedSections[trim($key)] = trim($value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $keyedSections;
}
```

Comment: `preg_quote()` doesn't have a default delimiter parameter -- you have to explicitly nominate `/` as the delimiter for your pattern to ensure that forward slashes are escaped in the input strings.  ...Or you can just change your pattern delimiters to `#` (which is escaped by `preg_quote()` by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with `preg_match_all()` which extracts all segments starting with any key and ending before any key. The `array_column()` call just discards earlier matches for later matches and sets up the desired associative result. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F9rQ9))

```
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply one dummy text of the printing and  two typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's one standard dummy text ever since the three 1500s.";

$keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$escaped = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keys));

preg_match_all('#\b(' . $escaped . ')\b\s*\K.*?(?=\s*(?:$|\b(?:' . $escaped . ')\b))#', $text, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_export(array_column($m, 0, 1));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'one' => 'standard dummy text ever since the',
  'two' => 'typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s',
  'three' => '1500s.',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but didn't have time to post it. And to clarify, random text and any keys specified in the input are sent to me from the front end, separated by commas. Here's how I process them:

```
public function getKeysArray(string $text, string $stringKeys): array
{
    $keysForPattern  = $this->prepareKeys($stringKeys);

    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all("/\b($keysForPattern)\s+(.*?)(?=\s+(?:$keysForPattern)\s+|$)/i", $text, $matches);

    $keys = array_values(array_filter($matches[1]));
    $values = array_map('trim', array_values(array_filter($matches[2])));

    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}

public function prepareKeys(string $keys): string
{
    $keysArray = explode(',', $keys);

    $keysArray = array_map(function($key) {
        return trim($key);
    }, $keysArray);

    return implode('|', $keysArray);
}
```